# MySQL : horizontal to vertical

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the original table :

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |

Note that the content of `type` is `VARCHAR` and therefore can be anything.

I want to get an output like that :

| id | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | NULL |

How can I achieve that using mySQL ?

EDIT, here is what i tried so far :

```
SELECT u.id, i.type, count(*) as total
FROM intervention i,
     intervention_user iu,
     user u
WHERE i.id = iu.user_id
  AND iu.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY i.type, u.id;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, where is the code?

Comment: Possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot tables in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857955/how-to-pivot-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: Your sample data and query have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.  I prefer `0` to `NULL`, so:

```
select id, sum(type = 'A') as a, sum(type = 'B') as b
from original
group by id;
```

If you want `NULL` values, one method uses `NULLIF()`:

```
select id, nullif(sum(type = 'A'), 0) as a,
       nullif(sum(type = 'B'), 0) as b
from original
group by id;
```