# How to transpose rows into columns dynamically in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Am building a mini project on how to display a school broadsheet, i have try all i know best but no solution, please i need your help.
I have three tables Students, Scores, Subject.

This is how i want my display to look like.

| Reg_no | Names of Students | Mathematics | English | Total | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TGD102 | Benjamin King | 60 | 55 | 115 | 57.5 |
| TGD103 | David Mathew | 50 | 45 | 95 | 47.5 |
| TGD104 | Mary James | 45 | 50 | 95 | 47.5 |
| TGD105 | Solomom David | 70 | 45 | 115 | 57.5 |

I have try my little best but only was able to display it this way below

| Reg_no | Student Names | Subject | marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TGD102 | Benjamin King | Mathematics | 50 |
| TGD103 | David Mathew | Mathematics | 45 |
| TGD104 | Mary James | Mathematics | 35 |
| TGD105 | Solomom David | Mathematics | 55 |
| TGD102 | Benjamin King | English | 45 |
| TGD103 | David Mathew | English | 35 |
| TGD104 | Mary James | English | 40 |
| TGD105 | Solomom David | English | 50 |

This was my code i used to display the table above.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Reg</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>marks</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        include('db/conn.php');

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student,score,subject 
                where student.stu_id=score.scostu_id
                AND score.scosbj_id=subject.subject_id ");
                
        while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row2['stu_id']; ?></td>
            <td><span style="text-transform:uppercase;"><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></span></td>
            <td><span style="text-transform:uppercase;"><?php echo $row2['subject_title']; ?></span></td>
            <td><span style="text-transform:uppercase;"><?php echo $row2['exam']; ?></span></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can i modified the above code to give me some thing like this.

| Reg_no | Names of Students | Mathematics | English | Total | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TGD102 | Benjamin King | 45 | 50 | 95 | 47.5 |
| TGD103 | David Mathew | 50 | 45 | 95 | 47.5 |
| TGD104 | Mary James | 60 | 30 | 90 | 45 |
| TGD105 | Solomon Dvid | 35 | 50 | 85 | 42.5 |

Comment: It is worth looking into how to use the JOIN syntax in SQL - this isn't the cause of your problem (although it can help) but is how most SQL is now written.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, an HTML problem, a CSS problem, or an SQL problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: First the subjects are from the databases, and i want the subject to be display horizontally on the table while the names and scores are display vertically under the subjects.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not optimize, but will do the job as you need.

```
<?php

$subjects = array();
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from subject");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $subjects[$row['subject_id']] = $row['subject_title'];
}

?>

<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<th>Reg</th>
<th>Name</th>
<?php foreach($subjects as $sbj) { ?>
<th><?= $sbj; ?></th>
<?php } ?>
<th>Total</th>
<th>Average</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    
    $scores = array();
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from score where scostu_id = " . $row1['stu_id']);
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
        $scores[$row2['scosbj_id']] = $row2['score_value'];
    }
    
    $total = 0;
    $count = 0;
?>
<tr>
<td align="center"><?= $row2['stu_id']; ?></td>
<td><?= $row2['name']; ?></td>
<?php
foreach($subjects as $sbj_id => $sbj_title) {
    $total += $scores[$sbj_id];
    $count++;
?>
<td><span><?= $scores[$sbj_id]; ?></span></td>
<?php } ?>
<td><?= intval($total); ?></td>
<td><?= (($total > 0 && $count > 0)?(round($total / $count)):0); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your respond, but the code gave me so many errors like Notice: Undefined variable: subjects in C:\xampp2\htdocs\RMS2\broadsheet.php on line 101 AND Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in AND ALSO Warning: Division by zero in.    Please can you try and simplify the code for me. Thanks

Comment: For clarity here is my database structure. i have three tables they are score, student and subjects. My Score database structure is this  score_id , scostu_id,  scoclas_id,  scosbj_id  ,  ass_1,  ass_2,  exam   The database structure for student is   stu_id,  reg_no,  name, 
 gender,  contact  And lastly the Subject database structure is subject_id  and  subject_title

Comment: You have to edit column's names to that you used in your database-tables to fix the errors. Notice that with the above code, I try to give you some inception to how to show the score table as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use following query to fetch the data in desired format

```
select stu_id, name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN subject_title = 'Mathematics' THEN exam ELSE 0 END) as Mathematics, 
SUM(CASE WHEN subject_title = 'English' THEN exam ELSE 0 END) as English, 
sum(exam) as Total, round(avg(exam),1) as Average from (select stu_id, name, subject_title, 
exam from student inner join (select scostu_id, subject_title, exam from score left join 
subject on score.scosbj_id = subject.subject_id) as t1 on student.stu_id = t1.scostu_id) 
as t2 GROUP BY t2.stu_id
```

It will give an output similar to this

[image]

Modify your HTML code accordingly to accommodate for additional columns. Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks so much for your respond and the code, it was helpful, but that is not what i wanted, if i should follow the above code means that i will be adding the subject manually but my goal is to display the subject dynamically from the database. No answere or solution has been given to my questions so far.

Comment: I think i have clearly explain what i wanted with pictures. I want to create a school broadsheet with subject displaying horizontally rather then vertically along side with the students names, scores, total and average. I have three tables student,score and subject as early mentioned. I need your helps please.

Comment: You can make necessary modification to the given solution. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48862792/21297591) link & give it a try.